# wordpress remove scroll bar from a specific page

Tags: php, css, wordpress, scrollbar

I need to remove vertical scrollbars from a *specific* webpage **only** in my site

http://historyofliverpool.com/test-2/

The page is made up from many php and css files, to I do not know where to begin editing, and do not want to alter the rest of the site.

Would a custom field on this page only solve my problem?
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I've tried adding 'overflow hidden' to the php template that 'creates' the page. But I really think it needs to be somewhere in the css (of which my theme has 6 css files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any `overflow: hidden` in your stylesheet.

Please try this:

```
.fullscreen {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Won't this just remove the bar on all pages though? I have a whole site that is created using the 6 css files but only want one page not to have scroll bars.

Comment: I've also tried adding this to the 'custom field' on the specific page, but it does not change anything, nor does it appear in the page source code.

Comment: Hey, I have solved the problem with a plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/css-plus/

has let me add css to that specific page only.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the scroll bar is easy; you would simply need to apply `overflow:hidden` to the `body` selector.

The real challenge is removing the scroll bar *on the correct page.* There are quick and dirty ways of doing this, but lets take our time and look at this sensibly:

### Child Themes

It looks like you're using the [Anglepane theme.](http://www.planetstarta.com/products/anglepane-the-comic-style-wordpress-theme/) As this is a commercial theme I'd recommend you first [create a child theme](http://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/wordpress-child-theme-tutorial) before making any changes. This way when the Anglepane theme is updated it doesn't remove your edits.

### Identifying the page - body_class()

The next step is identifying and selecting the page you want your changes to apply to. WordPress has the convenient [`body_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) function that adds CSS classes to the `body` element, allowing you to easily add styles on a page by page basis. Now it looks like your theme *isn't* using this function; so you should add this function by:

1. Copy the `header.php` file from the parent theme folder to your child theme folder so you can edit it
2. Find the `body` tag and alter it like so:

`<body <?php body_class( $class ); ?>>`

### Identifying the page - ID vs template

Once you've added the `body_class()` function you should find that your `body` element will have a bunch of classes that you can use; one of these will be the page ID, prefixed with `.page-id-`. You can now use that class name for your CSS. For example, if your target page had an ID of 3 you could use:

`.page-id-3 {
    overflow:hidden;
}`

While this works, I personally like to use page templates instead for targeting page-specific styles. One of the benefits to this is that it avoids mismatched page IDs between different environments. For example, I might want to change the background colour of my *about* page, which has an id of 4:

`.page-id-4 {
    background:red; // Works as long as the page ID is definitely 4
}`

That works great on my local copy of the site, but on the live site my *about* page has an id of 24. I avoid this by creating a [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) specifically for my *about* page. This way I can use the `page-template` selector instead, which is consistent across both environments:

`.page-template-about {
    background:red; // Now I work everywhere
}`

Hopefully that convers everything in sufficiently detail for you.